# How do I use more of the GPU RAM in google colab?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Im working on this deep learning project in pytorch where I have 2 fully connected neural networks and I need to train then test them. But when I run the code in google colab it is not much faster than running it on my CPU on my PC. I have colab pro btw. It is also using 0.6 out of the 40GB GPU RAM of the A100 GPU.

```py
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


device = torch.device("cuda:0")
# Define transform
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

# Load FashionMNIST dataset
trainset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST('./data', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
testset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST('./data', download=True, train=False, transform=transform)

# Create data loaders
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=1  , shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

# Define constant for classes
classes = ('T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
           'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle Boot')




# Define the fully connected neural network
class FCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_layers=1):
        super(FCNN, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.fc_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        if self.num_layers == 1:
            self.fc_layers.append(nn.Linear(28 * 28, 1024))
        elif self.num_layers == 2:
            self.fc_layers.append(nn.Linear(28 * 28, 1024))
            self.fc_layers.append(nn.Linear(1024, 1024))
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(1024, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        for layer in self.fc_layers:
            x = nn.functional.relu(layer(x))
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

# Modify the train function to move inputs and labels to the GPU
def train(net, criterion, optimizer, epochs=15):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 2000 == 1999:
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.2f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0

# Define function to test accuracy
def test(net):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in testloader:
            images, labels = data
            outputs = net(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    print('Accuracy: %d %%' % (
            100 * correct / total))

# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define the network
    net1 = FCNN(num_layers=1)
    net2 = FCNN(num_layers=2)
    net2.to(device)

    # Define loss function and optimizer
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer1 = optim.SGD(net1.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.0)
    optimizer2 = optim.SGD(net2.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.0)

    # Train and test network with 1 FC layer
    #print("Training network with 1 layer...")
    #train(net1, criterion, optimizer1)
    #test(net1)

    # Train and test network with 2 FC layers
    print("Training network with 2 layers...")
    train(net2, criterion, optimizer2)
    test(net2)
```

tried using different GPUS in google colab

tried adding this line to always use CUDA cores:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
```

and had the network use the device:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the batch size?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment you received says the easiest way to achieve a higher utilization rate of the A100 GPU would be increasing the batch-size.

It is important to keep in mind that the basic problem here is that you are testing a really simple model consisting of just a few layers and training on data that is too really simple, not that far from a toy dataset. Fashion-MNIST was created to be a drop-in replacement for the original MNIST dataset, it is more complex than it but its images are still grayscale and 28x28 pixels. In order to see a higher utilization rate of the GPU and, thus, a higher differential in training performance compared with your local you should try using a more complex model and dataset. Increasing the complexity of both the model and the data will make the differences quite easy to understand.